# Reloading a template in IONIC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 3 tabs:

```
<ion-tab icon = "ion-ios-medkit" title = "tab1" ui-sref = "tabs.tab1">
 <ion-nav-view name = "tab-tab1"> </ ion-nav-view>
</ ion-tab>
<ion-tab icon = "ion-clipboard" title = "tab2" ui-sref = "tabs.tab2">
 <ion-nav-view name = "tab-tab2"> </ ion-nav-view>
</ ion-tab>
<ion-tab icon = "ion-clipboard" title = "tab3" ui-sref = "tabs.tab3">
 <ion-nav-view name = "tab-tab3"> </ ion-nav-view>
</ ion-tab>
```

I want to click on each tab, the associated template to recharge.
for example, in the tab1 I write a text input phrase "hello world". when you click tab1, the template must be recharged and therefore the text field should be empty. (the same as when reloading a page and have written something in a text field.)

Comment: are u using diff controller for each..!?

Comment: Means you want to refresh tab view everytime appear?

Comment: @the_mahasagar yes! i do it..

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya yes! i need this

Comment: You can use $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Where should I put this? and what to replace?

Comment: you can set function on tab click and put this code in this function.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya I should put this in the controller?

Comment: in html - <ion-tab icon = "ion-ios-medkit" title = "tab1" ui-sref = "tabs.tab1" ng-click="refresh()"> and in js $scope.refresh() = function(){$state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true }); }